# Invalid Column Name using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I am attempting to use Dynamic SQL for the 1st time - Now i understand the gist of it to an extent however attempting to enter a parameter into a temp table using Dynamic SQL i am getting the "Invalid Column name" when i am simply try to enter this as text not intending to be a column.

On a side note its worth me mentioning i am running this on SQL Server 2005.

This is my executing query

```
SELECT ARCHV_FLAG,PATNT_REFNO,ACTIVE_NAMES,AINPT_REFNO INTO #TEMP FROM ACTIVE_NAMES WHERE PATNT_REFNO = 1 AND ARCHV_FLAG = 'C'

Fix SET @SQL = 'SELECT ARCHV_FLAG,PATNT_REFNO,'''+@TABLE +''' AS      [ACTIVE_NAMES],'+ @PK + ' INTO #TEMP FROM ' + @TABLE + ' WHERE PATNT_REFNO = '+ CAST(@PATNT AS VARCHAR (100))+ ' AND ARCHV_FLAG = ''C'''
```

Many thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE
    @SQL NVARCHAR(4000),
    @SQL1 NVARCHAR(4000),
    @TABLE VARCHAR (100),
    @PK VARCHAR (50),
    @PATNT INT

SET @PATNT = 1

CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    ARCHV_FLAG VARCHAR (1),
    PATNT_REFNO INT,
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR (100),
    PRIMARY_KEY INT
)

 CREATE TABLE #TABLE
 (NAME VARCHAR (100))

 INSERT INTO #TABLE (NAME) VALUES ('ACTIVE_NAMES')

SELECT * FROM #TABLE

 DECLARE Cur CURSOR FOR
 SELECT NAME FROM #TABLE

OPEN Cur

FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @TABLE
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @PK = (SELECT C.NAME FROM SYS.COLUMNS C 
       JOIN SYS.tables T ON C.object_id = T.object_id 
       WHERE T.name = @TABLE AND C.is_identity = 1)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ARCHV_FLAG,PATNT_REFNO,'+@TABLE +','+ @PK + ' INTO #TEMP FROM ' + @TABLE + ' WHERE PATNT_REFNO = '+ CAST(@PATNT AS VARCHAR (100))+ ' AND ARCHV_FLAG = ''C'''
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL

select @sql

FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @TABLE
END
CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
DROP TABLE #TEMP
DROP TABLE #TABLE
```

Comment: which version are u using ? it works perfectly fine at my end.

Comment: Just remember to add that in - I am running SQL Server 2005 unfortunately

Comment: can u update ur question, its confusing to where to add.

Comment: I have updated the question with the version sorry. Or do you mean something else.

Comment: i m telling about in question where did u updated ur question where the error is coming,because ur query is working fine at my end in `sql-server-2005`

Comment: The error is that the 1st @TABLE in the Dynamic SQL is being treated as a column rather than text. So when executing the SQL its saying its an invalid column when i do want it to be a column i just want it to be text. On line 4 of my question i added in about using SQL Server 2005

Comment: what are u executing with ? can u give the executing query ??

Comment: I have updated the question with the executing query

Comment: i am not getting any error. have a look https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMJTU.png also i cant see any ur executing query

Comment: What version of SQL are you running? When you ask for "executing query" do you mean what SP_EXECUTESQL will run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the dynamic SQL to treat your variable as a literal string and not a column name you'll have to wrap it in single quotes:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ARCHV_FLAG,PATNT_REFNO,'''+@TABLE +''' AS [ACTIVE_NAMES],'+ @PK + ' INTO #TEMP FROM ' + @TABLE + ' WHERE PATNT_REFNO = '+ CAST(@PATNT AS VARCHAR (100))+ ' AND ARCHV_FLAG = ''C'''
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: Hi George, Thank you for the comment i think we may be a step closer. However using this i am now getting this message.                                                                                                       Msg 1038, Level 15, State 5, Line 1
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name.

Comment: Have amended code snippet above to provide an alias for that column.

Comment: Hi George, When i use that i think it has too many ' in. As its put the rest of my script inside it (ie in red)

Comment: Oops, escaping the quotes can be a real head-case.  Removed the one after [ACTIVE_NAMES]